# Rails generate forms based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

When running the initial scaffold command, it auto generates a form for you based on your model. Is there any way to rerun this when you are generating a migration?

It would be awesome to be able to type rails g view user or w/e that would update your views according to your new model fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Allows you to do this.

Comment: I read the readme and didn't seem to find any generator like mentioned (formtastic)