# Automatically generate forms based on model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, mongoid

I have a model with many different attributes, and in the future I may add new attributes.

However, I don't want to edit my _form.html.erb file every time I need to add one line of code to a model file.

I'm using Mongoid (v2), so I'm already used to not having to do make a big fuss about adding a new attribute to my models.

Comment: there was a similar question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471174/rails-generate-forms-based-on-model), don't know if it helps with Mongoid

Comment: Thank you. Formtastic does exactly what I needed.

Comment: i wish you could do this with simple_form though...